# Access buffered audio data from HTML5 video using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, chromium-embedded

I am looking for a way to process the audio data of a (YouTube) video in advance to implement some audio visualisation. For this I am looking for a way to get the PCM data of buffered audio of the video element.

While it is fairly easy to make an Audiobuffer that loads and plays an audio file, I have trouble finding the buffered data of the video stream and copying it into a buffer.

Note that because I'm implementing this on a different piece of software with a CEF based built in browser, I'm currently executing the JS on the webpage, as if via the console.

Comment: For what it's worth CEF has the ability to capture audio. https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/a4d71d8fe2d7422c8e48128f55a503753e2d01c8/include/cef_audio_handler.h#L48

Comment: did you have any luck? Seem like this is kinda impossible in the browser

Comment: @Nikage I did not get much further because I had to focus on some other projects. I made a start just getting the real time PCM data out, but no luck accessing the buffered data.